# How can I update Minecraft for PS3?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I can't figure out how to update minecraft for PS3. I just bought the game and I would expect it to ask for a update but it hasn't. So how can I update Minecraft? Also would it take internet to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PS3 has been discontinued for years now, and the last update was [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/PlayStation_3_Edition_1.84) and that wasn't even a feature update, just bug fixes and removing features.

Legacy console has been discontinued and while maybe you'll get occasional fixes or something like that, don't expect updates. Feature updates will never come.

Comment: To build on what you said, If you were to buy Minecraft on PS4 (and I think PS5 since they both use the PS4 version), you can transfer all worlds from the PS3 version to the Legacy Console version of the PS4, then move those into the Bedrock version. By doing that, you would then receive all new updates when they release, and even use those old worlds to experience new features.